# How to configure "adb reverse" to run automatically?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, mobile, adb

I would like the "adb reverse" to run automatically when I run "expo start". Every time I need to open a new terminal instance, this is very annoying.

```
adb reverse tcp: 57464 tcp: 57464
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if it will work with expo, but it worked for me on react native. Try with start with your custom script from terminal f.e.
Add this line to your `package.json` scripts object.

```
"rn-start": "adb reverse tcp:57464 tcp:57464 && expo start"
```

You just start from terminal `npm run rn-start` or name it as you want to easily start without always reversing ports.

Comment: I tried run npm run android, but received a error. "unknown option `-l"

Comment: That worked! Thank you!

"android": "adb reverse tcp:57464 tcp:57464 && expo start --android"

Comment: Great! Happy coding! :)